# Radio ref on react

Tags: reactjs, forms, radio-button

I have radio input use want to use ref to show the result on console.

I always get second value even when I have choose the first one.
This is the constructor

```
this.inputKelamin = React.createRef();
```

and rendered like this

```
<div>
        Jenis Kelamin :
        <input name="kelamin" type="radio" value="laki - laki" ref={this.inputKelamin}/>
        Laki - laki
        <input name="kelamin" type="radio" value="perempuan" ref={this.inputKelamin}/>
        Perempuan
      </div>
```

onSubmit, I put it like this via console :

```
alamat : ${this.inputAlamat.current.value}
```

the result is always "perempuan"
This is not for production, just a learning purpose, thank you

Comment: why did you create `inputKelamin` ref, assigned it to 2 inputs, and then get the value of `inputAlamat`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using same `ref` for both the element, second `ref={this.inputKelamin}` overrides the first one and it always points to the second radio button.

From [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

> Refs provide a way to access DOM nodes or React elements created in the render method.

You should create 2 different refs for both inputs.

And you're checking the wrong property here

```
this.inputAlamat.current.value
```

value will always be the attribute value you gave `value="perempuan"`.

In case of radio you should look at the `checked` property, which tells you whether it was selected

```
this.inputKelamin.current.checked
```

Also, you might want to look at [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and [un-conntrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) components

Comment: Oh okay, thank you for the answer, that's what I mean.

Comment: @Siddharth Your solution works but why is the "checked" property not available when I do console.log(this.inputKelamin.current). I think this lack of explicit property is part of the confusion

Answer (score 0):

## In order to get just one data from multiple radio you cam simply do this :

Example with typescript :

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

function Form() {
  const inputKelamin = useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
  const inputLaki = useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement>;

  function handleSubmit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const selectedRadio = inputKelamin.current.checked ? inputKelamin.current.value : inputLaki.current.value
    console.log(selectedRadio);
  }

  return (
    <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      Jenis Kelamin : 
      Laki - laki <input type="radio" value="laki - laki" ref={inputKelamin} /> <br />
      Perempuan <input type="radio" value="perempuan" ref={inputLaki} /> <br />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default Form;
```